# when you want to test something on efficiency in erlang, which way do you use?

Tags: performance, erlang

In the Programming Erlang Chapter 8
Joe Armstrong use

> statistics(runtime)
>   statistics(wall_clock)

to test on efficiency,
is there any other way to test?
thks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`timer:tc/1,2,3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1) functions are nicely wrapped for this kind of measurements.

Comment: thks, I'm new to erlang. the tc/3 use apply/3 ,does the reture 'time' include the cost of apply/3?

Answer (score 0):

In those cases when `timer:tc` is not sufficient I use `fprof`, built in profiling tool. It have minimal runtime performance impact and nice readable and parseable output format.